# liquibase log table created under dbo schema Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am specifying schema in each change-log as shown below

```
<changeSet author="xyz" id="create_app_table">
    <createTable tableName="app" schemaName="CONF">
        <column name="application" type="varchar(100)"/>
        <column name="profile" type="varchar(100)"/>            
    </createTable>
<changeSet>
```

All user defined tables are created under CONF schema, but `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` tables are created under `dbo` schema.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and running liquibase script with below cmd

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

liquibase-maven-plugin.properties

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://xyz:1433;database=TEST
username=****
password=****
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I have multiple schemas under single DB, I want both log tables to be confined to its own schema.

I tried few options but none of them helped.

Firstly, instead of putting schema name in each changelog, I placed it in property file as `liquibaseSchemaName=CONF` it didn't work and all tables were created under `dbo` schema

Secondly, I placed schema name in pom file a shown below

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelog/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <defaultSchemaName>CONF</defaultSchemaName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But I get this error

> Cannot use default schema name CONF on Microsoft SQL Server because the login schema of the current user (dbo) is different and SQL Server does not support setting the default schema per session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I created the user with same name as of schema (It can be different also) in DB. These are the commands:

```
CREATE user CONF with password='xyz';
ALTER USER CONF WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = CONF;
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA :: CONF TO CONF ;
GRANT CONTROL TO CONF ;
```

Contents of liquibase.properties

```
url=jdbc:sqlserver://***
username=***
password=***
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
liquibaseSchemaName=CONF
```

Also added schemaName with each changelogs.

```
<changeSet author="xyz" id="create_app_table">
    <createTable tableName="app" schemaName="CONF">
        <column name="application" type="varchar(100)"/>
        <column name="profile" type="varchar(100)"/>            
    </createTable>
<changeSet>
```

With this I was able to create all tables including changelog tables under CONF schema.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a permissions issue. In your SQL Server management Studio, go in Security > Logins> Your User > right-click and get into Properties >User Mapping and check if the user has the default schema as CONF. If not, make the required changes.